# How to update a cell value in datagridview using c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to update the value of cells in a datagridview using c#, the value gets updated but during the code execution it gives this error message.

> Index was out of range, must be non negative and less than the size of the collection.parameter name: index

I have tried the column names as well as column index and also verified the row index, it actually updates the values but at each assignment statement it give the above error message and moves to next line. I am using this code,

```
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in SelectedItems.Rows)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["SKU"].Value) == orderItem.ItemId)
                        {

                            decimal currentQuantity = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
                            orderItem.Quantity = orderItem.Quantity + currentQuantity;
                            orderItem.Amount = orderItem.Quantity * orderItem.UnitPrice;
                            orderItem.Tax = orderItem.Tax * orderItem.Quantity;

                            orderItem.Discount = orderItem.Discount * orderItem.Quantity;

                            row.Cells["Quantity"].Value = orderItem.Quantity;
                            row.Cells["Amount"].Value = orderItem.Amount;
                            row.Cells["Tax"].Value = orderItem.Tax;
                            row.Cells["Discount"].Value = orderItem.Discount;
                            counter = 1;
                            CalculateTotal();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Which line in the code gives the error?

Comment: row.Cells["Quantity"].Value = orderItem.Quantity;
                            row.Cells["Amount"].Value = orderItem.Amount;
                            row.Cells["Tax"].Value = orderItem.Tax;
                            row.Cells["Discount"].Value = orderItem.Discount;

Comment: All these assignment / value update statements give error but when i click on it moves to next line and so on. The values get updated but i don't want this error / warning message to appear on each assignment statement.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Did but not working

Comment: I do not see anything in the posted code that “could” throw an “index out of range” exception. Are you sure the posted code is throwing this exception and it’s not getting thrown somewhere else? The `foreach` loop wouldn’t throw that error, nor would any of the `Convert` calls throw this error. In addition, the code is referencing the cell values using the “column” name and if didn’t exist, it would throw a column name not found exception. You may want to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: First i add items (rows) to the grid from the data using this code , then when some click on grid cell like in quantity change the quantity the I want to update all relevant cells which the above code does but with a message. Do you think it has something related to the first loading items (rows) in the grid?

Comment: ```while (reader.Read())
                        {
 orderItem.UnitPrice, orderItem.Discount, orderItem.Tax, orderItem.Quantity, orderItem.Amount);
                        }

Comment: Without seeing the line of code that is throwing the “Index out of range” error, I can only guess “where” it could be coming from. However, I AM confident it is NOT coming from the posted code since there is nothing in the code that uses an index. What is the `CalculateTotal()` method doing? Lastly… “Where/When” is the posted code called?

Comment: I have verified using breakpoints exception / message comes on "row.Cells["Quantity"].Value = orderItem.Quantity;", And i call this above code when a add item button clicked.

Comment: And please note that this is not and exception, a message comes i click on ok and it continues and calculates the totals as required. can i stop this message?

Comment: Hmmm… if a message pops up on that line of code `row.Cells["Quantity"].Value = orderItem.Quantity;` and you simply press ok… what is that message? It couldn’t be an index out of range message as stated in the question.